# How do I know if the kernel was build with CONFIG_MODVERSIONS?

Tags: kernel

I am running Ubuntu:

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise## Heading ##
```

And:

Kernel info:

```
3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:23:47 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I would like to know that whether this running kernel was build using `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` or not. Any command for that?

**Update**

```
#/usr/src/ubuntu-precise# make oldconfig | grep CONFIG_MODVERSIONS
/boot/config-3.8.0-38-generic:3420:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for SPI_PXA2XX_PCI
/boot/config-3.8.0-38-generic:4222:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for VIDEO_EM28XX_RC
/boot/config-3.8.0-38-generic:6694:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for NFS_V3
/boot/config-3.8.0-38-generic:6696:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for NFS_V4
```

no progress after this . hanging here for more than 30 minutes

Comment: Only suggestion: download kernel sources and type `make oldconfig | grep CONFIG_MODVERSIONS`.

Comment: @Danatela What exactly this command would do?

Comment: It will generate kernel config based on your existing config and echo it to the console. Then it will grep line containing `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS`. Probably, if you have this option enabled, you will have `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y` output.

Comment: @Danatela on an i3 processor it is taking more than 20 minutes, and still continuing, is it normal?

Comment: What is the stage? Downloading or configuring?

Comment: I already have the source code. When I typed the commands you gave, it hangs as can be seen in my update plz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14035/discussion-between-danatela-and-user2799508)

Comment: OK <I joined chat

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. Install the `dpkg-dev` package. This is needed for step 2.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
   ```
2. Download the source of the kernel you are currently using:

   ```
   apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
   ```

   That will create a directory in your current directory that contains the kernel source. For example, on 13.10 running kernel version `3.11.0-12-generic`, it created:

   ```
   /home/terdon/linux-3.11.0
   ```
3. Check if the option is set in the `~/linux-3.11.0/.config` file:

   ```
   $ grep CONFIG_MODVERSIONS  ~/linux-3.11.0/debian.master/config/config.common.ubuntu
   CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y
   ```

As you can see above, the option is set to `y` (on) by default so presumably, unless you have compiled your own kernel, the option is set in the kernel you are using.

Comment: using apt-get , I got "linux-lts-raring-3.8.0" what is raring ? is there anything wrong in having this?

Comment: I got y (on), but I do not know whether it was 'on' during compilation or not. In fact I dont know who installed linux on this system. So is there any other way without any presumption to this value in a running kernel ?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```bsh
grep MODVERSIONS /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

If you get

```
CONFIG_MODVERSIONS=y
```

then it's on.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of 2.4 kernel, the `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` can be found in the Makefile in folder `/usr/src/linux-2.4.x-xx/`.

Another symptom is an error message such as `unresolved symbol reference` for which one of the possible reason can be - `CONFIG_MODVERSIONS` is enabled, but the LKM is not compiled likewise.